# How to access the raw content from a response in Vapor 3 unit test?

Tags: swift, vapor

I'm coming from using tooling such as SuperTest with NodeJS and looking for relevant equivalents to support testing with Vapor 3 and server side swift.

I see a pattern of using making a testable application with Vapor 3 to do testing of endpoints, examples being https://github.com/raywenderlich/vapor-til/blob/master/Tests/AppTests/Application%2BTestable.swift and the write-up at https://medium.com/swift2go/vapor-3-series-iii-testing-b192be079c9e.

When using these in tests, the format generally looks something like:

```swift
func testGettingASingleUserFromTheAPI() throws {
    let user = try User.create(name: usersName, username: usersUsername, on: conn)
    let receivedUser = try app.getResponse(to: "\(usersURI)\(user.id!)", decodeTo: User.Public.self)

    XCTAssertEqual(receivedUser.name, usersName)
    XCTAssertEqual(receivedUser.username, usersUsername)
    XCTAssertEqual(receivedUser.id, user.id)
  }
```

(from [Vapor-TIL example code](https://github.com/raywenderlich/vapor-til/blob/master/Tests/AppTests/UserTests.swift#L87-L94))

In all of these examples, the return values are really set to be handed back to something decodable (the `decodeTo:` kind of setup). In some cases in my Vapor 3 code, I want to just validate some non-JSON encoded results - just simple strings, and validate the results - but I've not found the methods to get into the content or convenient ways to validate it with XCTAssert.

`response.content` is available, a container around the overall response (of type [ContentContainer](https://api.vapor.codes/vapor/latest/Vapor/Structs/ContentContainer.html)). Are there some examples or good ways at getting to the underlying content representation to validate them directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own additional methods in `Application+Testable` like

```swift
func getRawResponse(to path: String) throws -> Response {
    return try self.sendRequest(to: path, method: .GET)
}
func getStringResponse(to path: String) throws -> String {
    let response = try self.getRawResponse(to: path)
    guard let data = response.http.body.data,
          let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        throw SomeError("Unable to decode response data into String")
    }
    return string
}
```

and then call them to get either raw `Response` or decoded `String` like

```swift
func testGettingHelloWorldStringFromTheAPI() throws {
    let string = try app. getStringResponse(to: "some/endpoint")

    XCTAssertEqual(string, "Hello world")
}
```